# finish() takes me to main activity

Tags: android, activity-finish

i have a simple videoplayer with 3 activites. on my last activity i have

```
player.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return false;
```

//

```
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                    finish();
                    return true;
```

that does exactly what i want it to do when i press stop:takes me to previous activity

but..

```
player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i2) {
            player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buffering.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            errorDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;  
        }
    });
```

errorDialog has a small button(made by me) that calls finish() when you press it that takes me back to main activity(1st one) not the previous one(2nd one) and i dont understand why.even tried crating a new method in the activity with finish() in it but still does the same thing.
thank you for your time and support.

Comment: Where is the code from the Dialog that calls `finish()`?

Comment: the "dialog" is a custom button made by me :<Button
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="78dp"
                android:text="Return"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
                android:onClick="finish()" android:textSize="20dp"/>

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the formatted XML. Also, typically `android:onClick` should be set to the name of a function that *you* wrote so that you have complete control over what happens. In this case, `finish()` probably does not do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your calling of `finish()` is finishing your activity. You should use `cancel()` to kill a dialog.

Comment: tried now... acts the same :straight to main activity and thats what i want close the curent activity witch is the 3rd one and go back to the previous(2nd one)

Comment: Have you tried returning false from the onError method, perhaps that kills activity on true.

Comment: if i change to false it dosent change its functionality just pops up the error message that video cannot be played that i wanted to replace and add some more fuctionality

Comment: hmm, what code is executing in the listeners of `errorDialog` and I presume it doesn't kill the activity if you return true but don't show the dialog?

Comment: the listener errorDialog has a button with  android:onClick="finish()" and the return true or false only afects if it displays my custom layout for a error in streaming or both error dialogs.

Comment: As the answer says, shouldn't that button be `cancel()` or `dismiss()`

Comment: seems nobody understands that i want to terminate the CURRENT activity(number 3,started from number 2) and go back to the previous activity(number 2).The stop button does just that. The other button takes me to the main activity(number 1) what i dont want. I don't know how much clearer can i explain so someone can understand me and help.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog is not a new activity, it's a part or child of the current activity. You want to hide/remove the dialog box appeared on the screen once the button is pressed, so you should use ``` cancel()`` instead. ```
finish()` will destroy the current activity.

```
 case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                cancel();
                return true;
```

Comment: the MEDIA_STOP does what i want.destroy/close curent activity and go back to the previous one. the second one gets me back to main activity instead of the previous one.